# Computer doesn't start - changed mobo, PSU, GPU, RAM

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, troubleshooting

I have an ASUS P5W DH DELUXE with a Core 2 Duo E6400 CPU and 1GB x 4 ADATA RAM.

The computer failed to start, and I started troubleshooting.

- I changed the PSU (I bought 3 of them). [1x450Watt, 1x500Watt, 1x600Watt]
- I changed the mobo with another one (the same mobo Asus P5W DH DELUXE, now I have 2.)
- I changed 2 PCI-E cards. [ Asus Sapphire HD 4870 and Sapphire Radeon RS 230 ]
- I changed all the thermal compound for all of the parts with high quality.

The computer has the same problem. It fails to boot.

On the motherboard there are 2 power connectors (4-pin and 24-pin). The CPU fan fails to start if the cord 4-pin is plugged in. [KBMS, SPDIF, ESATA, LAN, USB] [Heatsink1 ] The CPU fan starts when you unplug the 4-pin  and just leave it with the 24-pin.

The Asus Sapphire HD 4870 LED is on and it says Heat protection. ASUS RS 230 does not have a light.

Both ways no signal input to the screen, no beeps to the speaker, nothing.

I tried CMOS reset, nothing.

The same with all the parts I have. [2 mobos, 2 PCI-e cards, 4x1GB memory ADATA, 3 PSUs]

The same problem and symptoms.

Do you have any ideas?
Corrupted CPU?
CPU Cooler?
All the PSUs are broken and I need new one?

I bought a new CPU and cooler and I'm still going crazy with the same problem.

Comment: To check the PSU, jump the power pins and see if it powers up. From everything you changed, I'd say the CPU seems likely, as if it was RAM it should at least beep. Might be a good idea to get a CPU tester or swap the chip. The cooler wouldn't prevent it from starting up, it would just heat up quickly and likely shutdown due to thermal trip, but it would at least start up temporarily.

Comment: Did you check the CMOS battery?

Comment: Thnx for answering scandalist .

The PSU are working fine i did jumped the power pins green and black and worked fine.

Comment: Also i changed the ram and checked without no beeps. I changed the CMOS battery too.

Comment: Well, that leaves CPU. Yes, symptoms definitely support it. Without CPU system will not start at all - obviously. If you changed for tested parts this is where I would check for problems next: CPU.

Comment: You've swapped everything and it's still not booting. I find this pretty odd. Here's an idea, plug in the PC into a different outlet. Preferably one in a different room.

Comment: Agree with @Geruta. Find a different outlet, and maybe put it into a testbed where theres no chance you're shorting it out somewhere from a screw in the case.

Comment: removing VGA and RAM and all peripherals, and power on with only CPU+MB+24pin+4pin power+case speaker. If you can hear the error beep(since there is no RAM) the MB+CPU should be OK. Then add RAM(1 stick at a time, and try different slot) + VGA to see if there is any output.

Comment: What is the make and model of your 600W PSU?  Only use that one for testing.  Some PSU makers cheat of on the specs.  There should be a grid on the side panel of the PSU indicating which voltages have how many amps or watts.  Post that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the P5W DH guide, the 4 pin ATX12V connector **IS** required.

I'd recommend you strip your case down to the bare minimum. PSU, mobo, CPU + FAN, 1 stick RAM - nothing else. You wont have any output to the screen, but you should get an idea if it is attempting to boot up (fan + beeps or lights).

If no sign of life, swap out the RAM. If it still doesn't 'start', the problem is most likely to be with the mobo or the CPU. Unless you have a wide range of resources, I'd recommend taking it into a repair shop - they should be able to confirm whether your CPU and/or mobo works at least. They key thing is to take one component at a time and place it in a known-working system.

If it does 'start' and you have access to a simple, low-powered GPU, you can add that back in. If not just use your normal one. Add disks, more RAM etc back in bit by bit.

If it fails at some point, take 2 or 3 components back out, and try the 'failing' component again - it may be the case that this component was the straw that broke the PSUs back.

Comment: I have done all this as you say before asking the superuser.com.

I have taken the Mobo and VGA Cards ,CPU 's + Cooler,  to an electronic engineer to check it.

Maybe tomorrow i have an answer

Comment: I have checked to an other room also friend.